# How to make one ObservableCollection dependent on other

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have ObservableCollection that contains some elements.In some Views to this collection binded some elements. But   one element is special, and this element must not displaying in other Views. Because I want have other collection dependent on first collection. Of course, I can add elements to first and two other collections in my ViewModel, but first collection changed in many places. So, from CollectionChanged event I can't modify second collection. How can I make one ObservableCollection dependent on other?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem correctly :)

I don't think you need a second/third/... ObservableCollection. Extend your view model with a SpecialVisibility property (the name is up to you) of type System.Windows.Visibility. Then, bind this property to the Visibility property of your data template.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <YourControl Visibility="{Binding Path=SpecialVisibility}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

These 'special' elements (i.e. the elements which should not be dispayed) just need the SpecialVisibility set to System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed.

Of course, this is not a solution to your problem of synchronizing many ObservableCollections. However, I think this might solve your problem. If using the CollectionChanged event is not an option for you, you might want to restructure your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class that inherits `ObservableCollection<T>` that has a reference to the original collection. This new class subscribes to the `CollectionChanged` event of the original and reacts to it by changing itself.